# How to suppress Labels names in jupiter

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

By default jupiter notebook is displaying labels context before graph. How to suppress them? Highlighted in yellow color.

[image]

Comment: Below is the code

g = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
g = sns.countplot(x='Country', data=retail_df2)
g.set_xticklabels(labels = list(retail_df2.Country.unique()),rotation=90)
plt.title('Sales by Region')
plt.show()

Comment: Add a semicolon `;` at the end of the last line.

Comment: wow such a simple solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a semicolon `;` at the end of the last line.